# Redis - AOF persistance

Tags: redis, nosql

As we can find in a Redis documentation (http://redis.io/topics/persistence), AOF Redis has 3 policies:

- no fsync at all
- fsync every second
- fsync at every query

I don't want to fsync at every query, because in documentation it is said that it is very slow. 
But part of my data is crucial and I cannot lose it. Is it possible to use policy where fsync is performed every second, but explicitly call fsync for given commands, to be sure that it is persisted on disk?

Answer (score 4):

Minor clarification: when used with `always` policy, AOF is written to only after **write** queries.

There is no standard way or policy that does that, but you can hack this to happen by wrapping your "crucial writes" and calls to `CONFIG SET` in a transaction, i.e.:

```
SET key1 "redundant"
MULTI
CONFIG SET appendfsync always
SET key2 "crucial"
CONFIG SET appendfsync everysec
EXEC
SET key3 "transient"
```

I tested this in v2.8 some time ago and it appeared to work but YMMV ;)